# Leaflet framework not resolving properly, "missing import statement"

Tags: webstorm

I have downloaded and installed the library in the "Languages & Frameworks" settings. It now recognizes one instance of `L` as leaflet, but the rest still show a warning squiggly with the "Missing import statement" message.  I have restarted WebStorm.  If I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> on any of the references, it does open `leaflet-src.js` as expected.

[image]

How can I get it to properly recognize Leaflet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logged as [WEB-30000](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30000), please follow it for updates